# swift3 reverse order for core data

Tags: uitableview, swift3, nsmanagedobject

I am new of Swift 3. Here is my situation:

I saved some data in the core data. Like `1,2,3,4,5...` I want to push them into the `tableView` with reversed order `(5,4,3,2,1)`.

Here are some of my code:

Records:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "List")

    do {
        let result = try managedContext.fetch(request)
        Array = result as! [NSManagedObject]
    }
    catch {
        print("some error.....")
    }
}
```

Push into cell

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    let item = Array[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = item.value(forKey: "data") as? String

    return cell
}
```

I tried something like

```
Array.reversed()
```

But the Xcode told me that the results are unused. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You can also add a `NSSortDescriptor` to your `fetchRequest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`reversed`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641355-reversed) is not mutating method, it will return object in reversed order so you need to use that return array.

```
array = array.reversed()
```

**Note:** It is better if property name start with lower case.